# p norm of matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I have a matrix $A \in C^{n\times n}$ with $||A||_p ≤ 1/2$  in some p-norm. I am wondering how to show that $$||(I+A)^{-1}-I||_p ≤2||A||_p $$

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$$\quad{||AB||_p\leq ||A||_p||B||_p\to ||A^2||_p\leq||A||_p^2\\||A||_p ≤ 1/2\to ||A^2||_p\leq\frac{1}{2^2}\\||A^n||_p\leq ||A||_p^n\leq \frac{1}{2^n}}$$now put $$\quad{(I+A)^{-1}=I-A+A^2-A^3+A^4-...\because\\(I+A)^{-1}(I-A+A^2-A^3+A^4+...+(-1)^nA^n)=I+(-1)^{n+1}A^n\\when \space n\to \infty \implies A^n\to0}$$so

$$\quad{||(I+A)^{-1}-I||_p=\\||I-A+A^2-A^3+A^4-...-I||_p=\\||-A+A^2-A^3+A^4-...||_p\\=||-A(I-A+A^2-A^3+A^4-...)||_p\\\leq ||A||_p||I-A+A^2-A^3+A^4-...||_p\\||A||_p(||I||_p+||A||_p+||A^2||_p+||A^3||_p+... ) \\
||A||_p(1+\frac 12+\frac 14+\frac 18+...)\\\leq ||A||_p\times 2
 }$$